# Linq: Select Most Recent Record of Each Group

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I want to get the latest record of each group from a SQL Server table using Linq.

Table Example:

[image: Original data]

I want to get this result:

[image: Desired result]

My Linq query returns one record for each company, but it doesn't return the most recent ones:

```
var query = from p in db.Payments
            where p.Status == false 
            && DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, p.NextPaymentDate.Value) == 1
            group p by p.CompanyID into op                                          
            select op.OrderByDescending(nd => nd.NextPaymentDate.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

What am i missing here? Why isn't the NextPaymentDate being ordered correctly?

**!!UPDATE!!**
My query is working as expected. After analysing @Gilang and @JonSkeet comments i ran further tests and found that i wasn't getting the intended results due to a column that wasn't being updated.

Comment: That looks right to me - 2015-11-13 03:30:50.127 *is* the most recent result in each case. Which result do you think is more recent than that?

Comment: @JonSkeet that image is an example of what i want to achieve. The real result show the older records (2015-11-13 03:12:21).

Comment: Ah. It helps if you show what you're *actually* getting... apologies for misreading the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right. sorry for misleading you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 var query = from p in db.Payments
             where p.Status == false
             group p by p.CompanyID into op
             select new { 
                 CompanyID = op.Key,
                 NextPaymentDate = op.Max(x => x.NextPaymentDate), 
                 Status = false
             };
```

The reason your query is not being ordered correctly is that your query does not do proper grouping. You did correctly grouping by CompanyID, but then you have to retrieve the maximum NextPaymentDate by calling aggregate function.

Status can be assigned false because it is already filtered by Where clause in the early clauses.

Comment: As far as LINQ is concerned, the OP's query is fine. It selects groups, and then selects a single element within each group. It would work perfectly in LINQ to Objects, as far as I can see. If it's not being converted into the right SQL, that sounds like a bug in the SQL converter to me.

Comment: @Gilang your solution seems to work. I need to test it further to know for certain. I have a new issue, my original table has more columns (PaymentID, RefPayment,Value, ..) how can i get the values of these columns in your query?

Comment: @Ricky You can add more column in the 'group by' clause like this `group p by new { p.CompanyID, p.OtherColumn, p.Another }`, then add it in 'select' clause by accessing it from 'Key' property like this `op.Key.CompanyID`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmm i think the way of calling `FirstOrDefault` and `OrderByDescending` function breaks the LINQ to SQL query

Comment: @Gilang: But it shouldn't - the provider should work out what it needs do to turn that LINQ into valid SQL. Do you agree that as a LINQ query in itself it's okay?

Comment: @JonSkeet By testing the query the LINQ to Object, I agree. But to LINQ to SQL, I haven't tested it. The solution I provided is basically a more common sense in SQL way. Perhaps we can test it by simple entities and see what query did LINQ generates?

Comment: @Gilang: Well yes - that's something I think the OP should have looked at to start with.

Comment: @Gilang and JonSkeet thanks for your help. after some further testing i detected why my query wasn't returning the expected results. the problem was related to a column in the table that was not updated when the last payment was received. once again thanks for your help.