# Retrieving last result from database for each id in a list in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a list of users and want to find the last results for each user. `id` on list is `int`, `id` in the database table is `long`.

I have to validate 2 columns.

I can retrieve this with a `foreach` statement in the list, but this method is too slow and I think it can be done with a much better angle.

I send the id and call a function:

```
var result = await _context.UserData
                           .OrderBy(a => a.id== id && a.Deleted == 0 && a.AccessType== 0)
                           .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This works but it is too slow.

Comment: What do you mean by "last results for each user"? You need to explain your data structure, it's impossible to guess what this code is trying to do.

Comment: You use `OrderBy()` as if it were a `Where()`. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Last entry in the table UserData for that user, in the code i submit for a single user it works fine, i just want to do that for multiple id's and return the value for each user

Comment: The orderby is to get last, entry in the table, it has 4 Million results i just want the last and retrieve that data.

Comment: @Baldroega last according to *what criteria*? Table rows have no order unless you specify one in the `ORDER BY` clause. Return which value? If you wanted to find the minimum or maximum value for a use you can use `GroupBy()` and then use `Max()` or `Min()`

Comment: Tempted to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685630/linq-select-most-recent-record-of-each-group

Comment: There's no "last" without a specific order. You could ask for the *latest* entry, which implies there's a `Date` field somewhere and you want the `MAX(date)` value per user. Or the *records* that match that max date. If IDs are unique and increasing, the latest record per user would have the maximum ID for that user

Comment: the id on the list is of type int, the id on the table is of type long?

Comment: In any case, ORMs aren't meant for reporting and analytic queries. What you ask can be implemented using ranking functions. For example`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by User order by ID Desc) RN` will return a row number called RN per user. If you restrict the results to only those rows that have RN=1 you'd return the latest row for that user

Comment: I do have a col with an increment id, but the code that i used returns the last one... its problably not the best, im in the very beginning in programming

Comment: First the database does not store items in order saved so you should always order by Date Time in Descending Order.  Use GroupBy : _context.Where(a => a.Deleted == 0 && a.AccessType== 0).GroupBy(a => a.id).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

This works but i do not want to get it  by date, this retrieves a lot of results, i just want one result for each user, and the last entry in the table for the respective id

```
var result =  (from u in Users join p in _context.UserData.Where(z=>  z.Deleted == 0 && z.AccessType == 0 && z.Data>=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)) on u.userID equals p.userID
                 into gj from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new {
                     userID = u.userID, 
                     InOut = x?.InOut
                 } ).ToList();
```